# C# Visual Studio Text formatting parameters on new lines so they are indented

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

So I can't figure out how on the Visual Studio settings to indent parameters that are on new lines, unless I manually do it.

```
            var results = myFunction(var1, var2, var3,
var4, var5)
```

I want

```
            var results = myFunction(var1, var2, var3,
                var4, var5)
```

Now this actually works if I put on one line and press enter after var3, but if it's already there it doesn't format when I press Advanced->Format Document

Comment: It should format when you type a semi-colon at the end, or when you type the closing bracket for the method. To format the whole document I usually go to the end (Ctrl + End), then delete and re-type the closing bracket for the namespace. Not sure why "Format Document" and "Format Selection" don't do this, though. I have ReSharper installed, so there may be some competing rules?

Comment: Yeah, I think ReSharper will do it, but I don't wanna install that. It's ok, not that big a deal, thanks for the input